# How can i remove order confirmation message on checkout Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Can someone please tell me how to remove the order confirmation message?
I'm using Roots and Stencil.

Answer (score 1):

BigCommerce does not have a template to edit the Order confirmation page. You could try this somewhat hacky method - use Javascript/JQuery to hide or edit the message.
For example,

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/checkout/order-confirmation"){
            setInterval(function(){
                if($('.optimizedCheckout-orderSummary [data-test="cart-shipping"] [data-test="cart-price-value"]').html().toLowerCase() == 'offline'){
                    $('.optimizedCheckout-orderSummary [data-test="cart-shipping"] [data-test="cart-price-value"]').html('Charges will be added offline');
                }
            }, 1000);             
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi that text found at checkout-en.json https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/localization/multi-language-checkout

Bigcommerce don't have any guide how to do.

if you know basic code then you have to copy paste checkout-en.json into your en.json file.